# Euclidean space without orthonormal basis

Tags: vector-spaces, normed-spaces

I've been thinking about:

> **Problem** Give an example of a nonseperable Euclidean space which
>   has no orthonormal basis.

**My Argument** I know if a Euclidean space $R$ has at most countable basis, then it has an orthonormal system. Moreover i know every linear space has Hamel basis. So, i am looking for a Euclidean space with uncountable basis.
**Trouble** How can I construct uncountable basis? Its just too many elements to deal with. Could you please help me with this?

**Edit** By Euclidean space i mean, a linear space with scalar product. Not necessarily complete or seperable like Hilbert spaces.

Comment: What do you mean exactly with *Euclidean* space? Personally, I use that terminology only to denote $\mathbb{R}^n$, $n<\infty$.

Comment: @DavidMitra Although those are called orthonormal basis, they are not bases in the usual sense of a vector space. You need infinite sums of them to get the whole space. They generate a space that is only dense in the whole space. The OP might be asking for existence of an actual basis that is also orthonormal.

Comment: @iamvegan Already taking a separable, infinite dimensional Hilbert space gives you the answer. Once you have constructed an orthogonal system $S$ that spans a set dense in the whole space, you cannot produce another vector that is orthonormal to all of them. Such a vector would be zero. On the other hand an infinite dimensional Hilbert space will have an uncountable Hamel basis. Therefore the countable orthonormal system $S$ is still not spanning (in the sense of linear algebra) the whole space.

Comment: Well, if that is true, then you don't need the word nonseperable. Separable Hilbert space does not have countable basis, and any orthonormal system is countable...

Comment: For such examples, it is usually a good idea to have a look at spaces of functions and $\int fg$ as scalar product

Comment: @Karene I didnt understand. Hilbert space has uncountable basis, but it is seperable. So do you mean i need to extend a Hilbert space?

Comment: @iamvegan First notice that a Hilbert space basis is not the same as a basis (called Hamel basis to distinguish them) of the same space as a vector space. A (Hamel) basis, by definition should generate every element as a (finite, by definition) linear combination of the basis. A Hilbert space basis only generates, by finite combinations, a dense subspace, and then you can get the remaining elements as infinite sums. A separable Hilbert space has a countable Hilbert space basis, but not a countable vector space (Hamel) basis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me put the comments in an answer.

> **Definition:** A vector space basis (or Hamel basis) is a system of vectors such that every vector of the space if a linear combination (by definition only finitely many of the coefficients are non-zero) of the vectors in the system.

Examples:

1. The bases you know of finite dimensional vector spaces.
2. $\{1,x,x^2,...\}$ basis of $\mathbb{R}[x]$
3. Hamel's basis of $\mathbb{R}$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space.

Non-example:

1. $\{1, \sin(nx),\cos(nx)\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ as a system of vectors of $L^{2}([0,2\pi])$. Because the function with graph the picture below (multiply the numbers in the picture by $\pi$) is not a finite combination of these elements. In particular a finite combination of these must be continuous but the graph below is not. [image: width=1]

> **Definition:** A Hilbert-space-orthogonal-basis (I put it with dashes to emphasize it is a concept by itself and not the union of the union of its parts) is an orthogonal system that is *complete*, where complete means that its linear combinations (finite as before) are dense in the space.

*Example:* The non-example above is an example of Hilbert-space-orthogonal-basis.

It is a theorem that when you have an a system of vectors that is an orthogonal-basis-of-a-Hilbert-space you can express every vector of the space as infinite linear combinations (Fourier series) of this system.

> **Theorem:** A Hilbert space with a countable Hilbert-space-orthogonal-basis (what is called a separable Hilbert space) can only have an uncountable vector space basis (a Hamel basis).

*Proof:* Assume $H$ is Hilbert and $B=\{v_1,v_2,...\}\subset H$ is countable. Let $E_n$ be the set of all linear combinations of $\{v_1,v_2,...,v_n\}$. Since $E_n$ is finite  dimensional it is closed in $H$. Since $H$ is infinite dimensional $E_n\neq H$. Therefore $E_n$ cannot contain any ball of $H$ (it is nowhere dense). But if $B$ is a basis then $H=\cup_n E_n$. Because $H$ is Hilbert, it is a complete metric space. By Baire category theorem it cannot be a union $\cup_n E_n$ of the countably many nowhere dense sets $E_n$.

> **Theorem:** All Hilbert-space-orthogonal-bases have the same size.

*Proof:* Assume $B$ is a countable Hilbert-space-orthogonal-basis of the Hilbert space $H$ and $A$ is another Hilbert-space-orthogonal-basis of $H$. Expand each vector of $B$ as an infinite linear combination (Fourier series) of $A$. If $b\in B$ is given as $$b=\sum a_i v_i,$$

with $a_i$ scalars and $v_i\in A$. Then, by Parceval's identity $$||b||^2=\sum |a_i|^2||v_i||^2.$$

Being this a convergent series of reals, only countably many can be non-zero. So, the countably many elements of $B$ are generated, as infinite combinations, (each) by countably many elements of $A$. In total only countably many elements of $A$, say $C\subset A$, are needed to generate all elements of $B$. Therefore, if $v\in A\setminus C$, then $v$ being orthogonal to all elements of $C$ would be orthogonal to all elements of $B$. Therefore $v=0$.

> **Conclusion:** An infinite dimensional separable Hilbert space (although it has a countable Hilbert-space-orthogonal-basis) it cannot have a vector space basis (a Hamel basis) that is also orthogonal.

*Proof:* From the theorems above.

1. An uncountable set cannot be orthogonal in a separable Hilbert space.
2. A vector space basis (a Hamel basis) of an infinite dimensional separable Hilbert space is uncountable.

Comment: thank you so much for your detailed answer and your time. Okay i now understand the two notions of basis and Hilbert basis. You'r saying: 1-In infinite dimensional Hilbert space all vector space bases are uncountable 2- Those vector space bases are not orthogonal. But i am confused that you are still using the word 'seperable Hilbert space'. So do we need somethig like "a Hilbert space with uncountable vector space is non-seperable" or are we concluding that the answer of my problem is "No there isnt"? I hope i am not annoying

Comment: @iamvegan Separability is a topological notion. A topological space is separable when it has a countable dense set. When a Hilbert space has a countable Hilbert-space-orthogonal-basis, this generates a dense set. If we then take all linear combinations with rational coefficients of this basis we get a countable dense set. That is why Hilbert spaces with countable Hilbert-space-orthogonal-basis are called separable. Still their vector space bases are uncountable.

Comment: I think i've just had the light bulb moment, thanks